How can a folder size be greater than the actual disk capacity on Ubuntu?
So, a little background:

I have a 2TB hard disk that serves as a backup for files (ext4 formated)
The disk was reporting +90% used space, so I bought a 4TB disk
Formated the 4TB to LVM with ext4

My plan was to just copy all the data from the 2TB disk (around 1.7TB according to df -h) to the 4TB disk, then reformat the 2TB disk to LVM and add it as extra space to the 4TB disk, creating a 6TB volume.
Now I began transfering folders and files. I have around 8.000.000 files (small and big both). Using MC to see the process of the copy all the time (running in screen OFC). Now I've began copying a folder and according to MC, it is now copying 2849GB (2.8TB) from the 2TB disk to the 4TB disk.
HOW?!?!?!?!?!?! How is this possible and what is happening here? If you need me to execute a command to have more information, let me know, I'm so lost. I've seen this only with pendrives bought on wish.com, but clearly, this is a hard drive bought newly here. How is it possible that a folder reports greater size than the disks max capacity itself?

Soft/hard links?

There are an insignificant number of them, yes. Oh..... You mean... when I start copy, the process starts to copy from the links too so it becomes a self-biting snake?

If the copy isn't link aware, it creates additional copies for linked files/directories, increasing the amount of data. In extreme, with a looping link, a link-unaware copy could produce an infinite amount of data and never finish.
ext4 also supports sparse files that may inflate during (simple) copy but those are rarely used.
Other potential factors are data deduplication or compression but with ext4 that is not an issue.
